# Stanford C++ Library Map Vector Error

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

This is on Mac OSX 10.8. Using the Stanford CPP libraries (available at http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/materials/cppdoc/), and using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "simpio.h"
#include "map.h"
#include "vector.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Map<Vector<char> , Vector<char> > frequencies;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error, on Xcode 4:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_function.h:227:20:
>   Invalid operands to binary expression ('const Vector' and 'const
>   Vector')

Why is this?

Comment: Umm, no matter what the instructor told you, that library is not used outside your classroom.

Comment: Use Vector<char> as key type looks suspicious.

Comment: Please post the entire text of the compiler output. Something went wrong in the `Map` template instantiation, and the errors should trace back to `main`.

Comment: Show `227`(+- 2) line from `stl_function.h`.

Comment: @soon No, that will not be helpful.

Comment: @soon because that's the GCC library implementation, not the Stanford library implementation. Often the innermost level of template error is a highly-general operation that reveals nothing about the underlying cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick glance at the [`Vector` documentation](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/materials/cppdoc/Vector-class.html) shows that it doesn't support comparisons, which are a conceptual necessity for any key type.

You would have to specify a comparison functor to `Map`, or define `operator <( Vector< T > const &, Vector< T > const &)` such that the library finds it by argument-dependent lookup.

But, your library seems to lack support for comparison functors, and `char` cannot be used as a hook for argument-dependent lookup, so it seems that the Stanford library doesn't support this. A wrapper class (somewhat advanced technique) would be a workaround but it would be a pointless effort.

It's very unfortunate if your curriculum doesn't cover the ISO Standard Library. Would have expected better from Stanford.

---

**EDIT** Oops, you can just define `operator<` in the global namespace since `Map` isn't in a namespace. This should do the trick.

```
template< typename T >
bool operator < ( Vector< T > const &lhs, Vector< T > const &rhs ) {
    return std::lexicographical_compare(
        & lhs.get(0), & lhs.get( lhs.size() ),
        & rhs.get(0), & rhs.get( rhs.size() ) );
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to compare Vectors though, I'm trying to make a Map with Vector<char> as a key type, and Vector<char> as a value type.

Comment: @user2457967 How will `Map` use `Vector` as a key type without performing any comparison operations? If the map is implemented as a sorted structure, it will need a less-than operation, and if it's a hashed structure, it will need equal-to.

Comment: @user2457967 The key for a Map must support the ability to do comparisons, or else Map cannot function.

Comment: @user2457967 Woops, since the library isn't enclosed in a namespace, actually there's a simple solution. See edit.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I think I added your function, but it still didn't compile.

Comment: @pyrrhic You should never need to modify a library file. Try putting the function after the `#include` lines. It just needs to be declared before it's used (in `main`).